# How can i design a sequence diagram where the actors dont interfere with each other?

Tags: uml, actor, sequence-diagram

i've been trying to design a sequence diagram for a storage system in a shop .

There are 3 actors (boss , employees and supplier) who can do different jobs on the system .

For example supplier can only inform the system for the new arrivals. Employee can only check if a product is in stock .Boss can check products in stock ,get information about the products etc.

The problem here is that the actors dont intefere with each other . Should i design 3 different diagrams or should i just design a diagram where the 3 actors are next to each other but the one does not effect the other?

Any help would be valuable .

Comment: There is no general rule except to keep your diagrams clear and then not too complex. Out of the fact the answer is opinion based to know the number of actors is not enough to know the full complexity so to know if all can be shown in the same diagram or not. `actors ... who can do different jobs on the system` : if your goal is to describe what they do they are not actors because by definition actors are external to the described system.

Comment: The actors I mentioned, use the storage system. So , I suppose it's like the example with the ATM where the actor (a human) is trying to deposit money. In my example an employee or someone from the other 2 , is trying to use the system. Aren't they external to the system?

Comment: yes they are, I just reacted in case on your sentence which seemed to say the opposite, while using the conditional however

Answer (score 1):

A sequence diagram aims to represent an interaction scenario.

You can of course represents several islands of unrelated interactions (e.g. supplier/product/stock and employee/stock/product). But this makes the diagram appear unnecessarily complex without adding value.

**Conclusion**: if the interactions are unrelated, you‘d better represent them in 3 separate diagrams, each appearing simple to understand and focusing on one logical sequence.

**Hint:** keep your diagrams as simple as possible but not more.

*Why? Any diagram of more than 6-7 elements will appear difficult to understand to the average reader. This is a consequence of findings proven in experiments on short term brain memory by Herbert Simon in the 70s. Experienced readers can understand much more complex diagrams because they work with chunks of elements (patterns) that they are able to group together and they can mentally handle the group as if it was a single element. Keeping diagram simple therefore helps most of the readers to focus on the elements that matter, and making more diagrams facilitates grasping the complex system without having to chunk elements.*